# Select rows converted to xml

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to join multiple tables in a single query into single column for later deserialization, and I can do this by using xml:

```
SELECT (SELECT * FROM table as B WHERE B.Id = A.Id FOR XML) as Serialized FROM table as A
```

And it will give some serialized column with entire row serialized into it.
Obviously, there is a problem of sub-query - you should put this annoying WHERE subquery and not just `Id=Id`, but determine primary index and add aprporiate fields:

```
SELECT (SELECT * FROM manyToManyTable as B WHERE B.SourceId = A.SourceId AND B.TargetId = A.TargetId FOR XML) as Serialized FROM manyToManyTable as A
```

And it will become worse for system-versioned tables, because it will add additional index of its own. Is there a way where I can say just:

```
SELECT /* row as xml*/ FROM manyToManyTable
```

Or:

```
SELECT (SELECT * FROM SAME_ROW() FOR XML) as Serialized FROM manyToManyTable
```

without diving deep into schema of table?

Comment: Care to explain why downvote? By the way, you can flag question, if it is inappropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly you're looking for `FOR XML PATH` in an `OUTER APPLY`, e.g.:

```sql
create table [dbo].[Table] (
  Id int not null,
  Value nvarchar(50)
);
insert [dbo].[Table] values
  (1, N'Alpha'),
  (2, N'Bravo'),
  (3, N'Charlie');
```

Where:

```sql
SELECT Serialized
FROM [dbo].[Table]
OUTER APPLY (SELECT [Table].* FOR XML PATH) xmlColumns (Serialized)
```

Yields:

```
Serialized
----------
<row><Id>1</Id><Value>Alpha</Value></row>
<row><Id>2</Id><Value>Bravo</Value></row>
<row><Id>3</Id><Value>Charlie</Value></row>
```

Or if you don't like the `<row>` element names supply your own with:

```sql
SELECT Serialized
FROM [dbo].[Table]
OUTER APPLY (SELECT [Table].* FOR XML PATH('Foo')) xmlColumns (Serialized)
```

Yields:

```
Serialized
----------
<Foo><Id>1</Id><Value>Alpha</Value></Foo>
<Foo><Id>2</Id><Value>Bravo</Value></Foo>
<Foo><Id>3</Id><Value>Charlie</Value></Foo>
```